# Fast Median Estimation: figure out the proof of correctness and error calculation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, median

I found [the Yuval Shavitt's FAME algorithm](https://www.eng.tau.ac.il/%7Eshavitt/courses/LargeG/streaming-median.pdf) but I can't figure out the proof of correctness and how to calculate the median error. It would also be interesting to compare this with the case of continuous random numbers.Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it’s worth emailing Shavitt to ask if there is any more formal presentation of the algorithm and it’s correctness.